# What functions are called between subview's awakeFromNib and view's viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewdidload, autoresize, awakefromnib

I have a UIView/UIViewController (`UIViewController`) within storyboard that contains a custom UIView (`CustomView`) that has an associated .xib file. I am encountering the following phenomenon when I load `UIViewController`:

- `CustomView`'s `awakeFromNib` function is called
- SOMETHING(?) sets my subview's frame to a height of 0.0; stack trace reveals `[UIViewController autoresizedArchivedView]` (relevant?)
- `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function is called

Any idea what this "something" that occurs between `awakeFromNib` and `viewDidLoad` and how I might control it?

Comment: That "something" is most probably the autolayout. Try calling the `awakeFromNib` of your custom view in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` just to see if it works.

Comment: @Eugene: To see if what works? Calling the custom view's `awakeFromNib` from within the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does not seem to set the custom view back to its original height (as set from storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Geometric properties are not set on archived objects until *after* viewDidLoad:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog (@"%@ %@",
               NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
               NSStringFromCGRect(self.testView.frame));

    }

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        NSLog (@"%@ %@",
               NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
               NSStringFromCGRect(self.testView.frame));
    }


    - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        NSLog (@"%@ %@",
               NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
               NSStringFromCGRect(self.testView.frame));
    }
```

Log:

```
    viewDidLoad {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
    viewWillAppear: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
    viewDidAppear: {{80, 224}, {160, 274}}
```

Comment: My log file shows: viewDidLoad {{0, 249}, {320, 0}}, viewWillAppear: {{0, 249}, {320, 0}}, viewDidAppear: {{0, 249}, {320, 0}}. The subview is a custom UIView with an associated .xib file.